# Use Lua sandbox with MediaWiki under Windows

Tags: lua, mediawiki, sandbox

I am running a MediaWiki (1.34.1) on a Windows server. The wiki contains some Lua modules which are executed by the Scribunto extension running Lua 5.1.4.
Up to now I am using the luastandalone but I would like to use the luasandbox engine (should be faster).

With the lastest PHP luasandbox release 4.0.2 PECL provides a Windows DLL (https://pecl.php.net/package/LuaSandbox/4.0.2/windows).

With this DLL is it possible to run luasandbox under Windows?
How can I install/configure the PHP/MediaWiki/Scribunto environment to use this DLL?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I don't think that follows.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff The OP is asking to use LuaSandbox inside of MediaWiki, which is where it was built and intended to be used for. The fact that it's not a drop-in Lua replacement doesn't mean it can't be used for that purpose.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - You're right.

Comment: Any hints how to install/use it under WIndows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use LuaSandbox under Windows with IIS, and is in fact an especially convenient way to do so, You simply install the necessary Lua binary as a *PHP extension* into your existing PHP interpreter (which you know is working, because MediaWiki is implemented in PHP).

I discuss this at some length in [this conversation on the MediaWiki page Extension Talk:Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:W6pj4xql1tjpvfyb) but I'll provide the essentials here as well:

> I did finally get Lua working under IIS on Windows 10, with PHP 8.0. The trick was, I abandoned the luaStandalone binary entirely, and instead downloaded the (just released less than 2 months ago) PHP luaSandbox extension from PECL:
>
> https://pecl.php.net/package/LuaSandbox
>
> Click on "DLL", then choose the build that matches your PHP install (for me it was PHP 8.0, x64, non-thread safe — the details are at the very top of the long, long output of `php.exe -i` from a command line), and download the provided zip file. After extraction, only two files are important:
>
> - `php_luasandbox.dll`, a PHP extension module that goes wherever the rest of your extensions are. (For me, `C:\Program Files\PHP\v8.0\ext\`.)
> - `lua5.1.dll`, an embeddable Lua interpreter that gets installed in the directory where the `php.exe` binary lives. (For me that was `C:\Program Files\PHP\v8.0\`, the parent directory of the extension location).
>
> After that, just edit your `php.ini` to add:
>
> ```
> extension=php_luasandbox.dll
> ```
>
> and edit `LocalSettings.php` to include:
>
> ```php
> $wgScribuntoDefaultEngine = 'luasandbox';
> ```
>
> (making sure to remove or comment out any lines about luaStandalone).
>
> Relaunch IIS, and that should be that. If you have MediaWiki working at all, you've already got PHP running, so using Lua *that way*, as a PHP extension, just makes eminent amounts of sense.

As I note in the MediaWiki discussion, there's *some* degree of controversy over this because the Lua developers themselves are sort of down on the notion of a "sandboxed Lua". [They do not believe](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) it to be a technically viable method of restricting Lua's access to and consumption of system resources. But on Windows, most of the restrictions they recommend imposing on the **standalone** binary are not available from the OS anyway, making the situation even more confusing/unclear.

Comment: Thanks!! The key information I needed was to check which lua dll to use (php.exe -i). It's working now (and it's *much* faster :-)